# MySQL - A way to join all found rows in one column

Tags: mysql

CREATE TABLE `dummy` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `name` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

and running this query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`name` SEPARATOR "||") FROM `dummy`
```

This query joins name column in all rows with || in a single column. BUT, the result is truncated with mysql configuration as explained in [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) :

> "... result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len  system variable, which has a default value of 1024 ..."

Also in manual it is said that this setting can be changed in run time by the following syntax:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```

Does changing this configuration works in all mysql server environments? If not, how can I achieve the same result without GROUP_CONCAT without limits?

Also, I think that changing the configuration will not solve my problem because I don't know what to set the value of group_concat_max_len because number of rows in dummy table can be any number.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to do this in MySQL and not in some programming language?

Comment: I'm not sure how the `group_concat_max_len` setting behaves. However, the fact that you (effectively) need to set it to infinity in order to make your query work, something is wrong with it: you should try to achieve the same result without using the group concat

Comment: Tatu - If I had 300,000 rows, looping through all rows and joining that would not be fast as native MySQL

Comment: Martijn - Yes, you are completely right but how??

Comment: Tatu is right. Doing a SELECT id, name FROM dummy and looping through the results is how it's done. That's the way databases are supposed to be used.

You can use a stored procedure or use a for loop in the programming language. The programming language might be slower as you say but you do need access to the data from your code don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using stored procedure to accomplish your task? You can create a temporary table with a single row/column and append to it while fetching rows from your table. In the end just `SELECT` the single value from the temporary table.
You can find information about stored routines in [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines-syntax.html) and other places.

Comment: Hi eugene, I can not use stored procedures due to version requirements